# Form data not updating by using update_attributes in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to update user's data in users table by using a "update" action in "users" controller in Rails4. I am using PostgreSQL Database.

**Problem:** When I go to "edit" action, I gets the form rendered properly. After filling data in 1 or multiple columns in the form, when I press "Update Profile" button to update the user's data, then form page redirects and gets back to the same edit page but now the url's have changed. The data is not getting saved in the database. It is only displaying in the form fields only. Even the profile pictures are uploading but their link are not saving in the database.

**Example:**

Before Update -> URL: http://localhost:3000/users/edit?id=2

After Update -> URL: http://localhost:3000/users/update/2

But the new entered data didn't got saved in the database. I also checked rails server log but I didn't understood, what is wrong with the form. Through rails console I tried to update the user's data but still I am unable to save data in the database. Please check the screenshots.

**Rails Server Log:**
[image]

**Rails Console:**
[image]

**Users Controller:**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def edit
        @user = User.find("#{@current_user_id}")
      end

      def update
        User.transaction do
          @user = User.find(params[:id]).lock!
           if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
             Welcome.profile_data_updated(@user).deliver_now
             redirect_to(:controller => 'users', :action => 'profile', :id => @current_user_id)
           else
             render('edit')
           end
        end
      end
    protected
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :user_image, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :email, :street_address, :city, :state, :country, :postal_code, :mobile_number)
  end
end
```

**CreateUsers Migration File:**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :username, null: false
    t.string :user_image
    t.string :first_name, null: false
    t.string :last_name, null: false
    t.string :password_digest, null: false
    t.string :email, null: false
    t.string :street_address
    t.string :city
    t.string :state
    t.string :country
    t.string :postal_code
    t.string :mobile_number
    t.string :validation_code
    t.string :user_status, null: false, :default => '1' # 0 for deactivated
    t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates_confirmation_of :password

    include CarrierWave::RMagick    
    mount_uploader :user_image, ImageUploader


    validates_presence_of :username, :format => {:with => /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/, :message => 'Username can only contain Alphabets'}
    validates_presence_of :first_name,:last_name,:password,:email
    validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
    validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, :on => :create
    validates_numericality_of :postal_code, :mobile_number, :on => :update

    def full_name
        "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end 

    def location
        "#{street_address}, #{city}, #{state}, #{country}, #{postal_code}"
    end
end
```

**Update.html.erb File:**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: { action: "update", :id => @user.id }, method: :post, html: { multipart: true, class: "ui form"} do |f| %>
        <div align="center"><%= image_tag @user.user_image.to_s, :size => "200x200" %></div>
        </br>
        <div align="center">
        <%= f.file_field :user_image %>
        </div>

    <h4 class="ui dividing header">Billing Information</h4>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Name" %>

        <div class="three fields">
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Username' %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => 'First Name' %>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => 'Last Name' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Billing Address" %>
            <div class="fields">
                <div class="ten wide field">
                    <%= f.text_field :street_address, :placeholder => 'Street Address' %>
                </div>
                <div class="three wide field">
                    <%= f.text_field :city, :placeholder => 'City' %>
                </div>
                <div class="three wide field">
                    <%= f.text_field :postal_code, :placeholder => 'Postal Code' %>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "State" %>
            <%= f.text_field :state, :placeholder => 'State' %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Country" %>
            <%= f.text_field :country, :placeholder => 'Country' %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h4 class="ui dividing header">Contact Information</h4>
    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="disabled field">
            <%= f.label "Email" %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, :disabled => true %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Contact" %>
            <%= f.text_field :mobile_number, :placeholder => 'Mobile Number' %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h4 class="ui dividing header">Security</h4>
    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "New Password" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'New Password' %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Retype Password" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Retype Password' %>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.submit "Update Profile", data: { disable_with: "Updating..." }, class: 'ui green button pull-right'%>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

**My Opinion:**

1. Maybe there is a mistake in "update" action. But if there will be any mistake then Rails must have thrown an error on processing the form.
2. The protected method "user_params" maybe protecting the data from being submitted. As I am not filling all the form columns. I am entering data in 1 to multiple form fields.
3. There may be blunder in edit form.

**New Server Log:**
[image]

Users Controller with Signup Action:

```
def signup
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        Welcome.welcome(@user).deliver_now
        redirect_to(:controller => 'access', :action => 'login')
    else
      render('signup')
    end
  end
```

Signup Form:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :html => {:multipart => true }, :url => {:controller => 'users',:action => 'create'})  do |f| %>

                    <h3 class="nomargin">Sign Up</h3>
                    <p class="mt5 mb20">Already a member? <%= link_to "Login" , {:controller => 'access', :action => 'login'} %><br><br>

                    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                    <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' ,placeholder:'Username' %></br>

                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' ,placeholder:'Email' %></br>

                    <label class="control-label">Profile Picture</label>
                    <%= f.file_field(:user_image) %></br>

                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="row mb10">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First Name' %></br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name' %></br>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb10">
                        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Password' %></br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb10">
                        <label class="control-label">Retype Password</label>
                         <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Retype Password' %></br>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Sign Up</button>     
                <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your 1st log posted indicates an unpermitted parameter upon update => :password_confirmation.

Please try adding  :password_confirmation to your strong parameters validation.

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :user_image, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :email, :street_address, :city, :state, :country, :postal_code, :mobile_number, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

Please let me know how it goes.

**UPDATED section after strong parameters changed include form field password_confirmation and discussion**

Please try changing this:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def edit
        @user = User.find("#{@current_user_id}")
      end
```

To this:

```
      class UsersController < ApplicationController 
      # Precursor action to rendering the edit user view
        def edit
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end
```

Comment: The unpermitted parameter was a problem, but probably not the only one. It would be helpful to see the server log now after the change. The next clue is there.Please post the log to your original question.

Comment: The logs are always same. But the form data doesn't saves. I am also using some disabled fields in the form, maybe they are causing some problem. But I still know something else is causing problem. I am uploading a new server log, pease check.

Comment: I got a lead here. When I am using "update_attributes" then the data is not submitting in the database. But when I used "update_attribute", then the data got saved into the database.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.I see the new log. The update was committed successfully to user with ID 3 according to the COMMIT status 200. What do think the record  is not updated? What is the behavior/data that is not there/is there?

Comment: Everytime I gets the message of committed successfully but this commit never happens in the database. This is the problem.

Comment: I see something, but I'm not sure why it's happening--why is the query for users.id != 3 before the update? Let me look more in depth to see if I see something that would cause this strange behavior. But the SQL query simply concludes with a 200 status. Also, "update_attributes"" is fine. You should use it.

Comment: Let me give an example. When the form is rendered, I choose country field to enter "India" there. I wrote India and clicked the Update Profile Button. Then page redirects and gets back to the edit form. But now I am able to see India in the country field. Then I checked database but the country column with India is not there. Then I refreshed the edit page and that country filed with India displaying is not there. That field is again empty. This is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88932/discussion-between-val-asensio-and-shubham-abrol).